# Windows 2008 Print Server issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-server

I have a dedicated windows 2008 server I use as a file server and print server at my home office.

Whenever I print documents from one of my clients, I see the document hit the queue on the server immediately (says its in "printing" status), but it takes FOREVER to print out (like over 5 minutes).  But, printing the same document locally from the server takes 4 seconds.

It's an HP 1006P laser printer.   I am running 32-bit 2008 Server.  Installed the Vista drivers ( updated to latest version ).

Tried updating the drivers on the clients too and no dice.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it helps.

```
Local Computer Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers

Allow print spooler to accept client connections > to enabled

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers\

Point and Print Restrictions > to disabled
```